# Why log status is success and not failed?

Tags: apex, exception

Lets say I have a VF page and a controller.
I would like to know why I don't see any errors coming on the log status when there are exceptions thrown when the code runs.

I am trying to **deliberately** make the apex code fail (throw an exception) and expect to see its failure on the log status generated in Developer Console when I open the VF page. I don't want to catch this exception. I would like to see it coming on the log.

When I open the page I do see the error... 
[image]

**However, somehow the generated log status is always success and I don't get the signal that something went wrong. It's not make sense.**

[image]

When I open the log I do see the exception thrown. 
[image]

Please advise.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you use a try-catch block? You'll only see the exception at the top level if you fail to catch it.

Comment: It would be great to see a snippet of the code, you can remove any sensitive bits, but as sfdcfox mentions, try-catch blocks or other defensive coding techniques could be inherently blocking a failure.

Comment: I too have observed this pattern with uncaught errors in Visualforce.

Comment: I think you didn't get me .. I will edit my post. :)

Comment: I've seen this as well with Visualforce -  https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/697949945165295616.
Execution stopped on an exception, but the developer console log has the Success Status.

Comment: I just realized that this is all about Visualforce. I've always noticed that Visualforce tends to "eat" exceptions. The status almost always shows up as Success. Let me draw up something.

Comment: @DanielBallinger It's always done that. I'm actually kind of surprised that this question *is not* a duplicate, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @sfdcfox Interesting. As I'd mentioned on twitter, I thought it might have been a Spring `16 thing. I guess I look harder for oddities around release time.

Comment: @sfdcfox what do you mean by saying that you are surprised that this is not a duplicate? :)

Comment: @RonDaniel This behavior's been around ever since debug logs were a thing, and yet nobody's really called it out like this until very recently. I kind of expected someone to notice it and ask like... years ago.

Comment: @Ron This issue is now fixed. Take a look at Daniel's updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visualforce *always* shows successful during logging. I suspect that's because the underlying Visualforce layer catches the exception and renders it into something useful (if not a bit obnoxious, since it also wipes out the view state for the user). This behavior is not new to Winter '16, but has been around for quite a while (as far back as I can recall).

In fact, I think I plan on bringing this up as a bug with R & D, if I can get it that far, because it really does make the Status field less useful than it should be, and makes it especially hard to track down failures when you're trying to debug remotely and you've got hundreds of logs from users that all show successful when some of them really are not (and are the only ones you happen to care about).

Just a couple of weeks ago I had an error on a Visualforce page that was very chattery (about three or four logs per single transaction to work around limitations), and so I had to dig through about 2 or three pages of logs by opening them one at a time until I found the one that I wanted. It's a very terrible experience and can make tracking down errors a lot more challenging than it should be.

Comment: Yes. This is what I also feel. 
Thanks a lot @sfdcfox.

Comment: I've raised this as support case 13205328. Will see if Salesforce are willing to clean it up.

Answer (score 6):

Resolved in Summer '16 - [View Visualforce Controller Exceptions in Debug Logs](https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_debugging_logging_vf_exceptions.htm?edition=&impact=)

---

I raised this with Salesforce support in Case 13205328.

They came back with the known issue [Exception Details not logged in Debug Logs if happens in Constructor context](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T2jGAAS).

This seemed to agree with my quick tests. If the exception occured in the constructor the Status showed success. The same exception from a property in the controller showed as Status "Divide by 0".

Comment: I just noticed this is fixed while developing a page today. Case closed!

Comment: @AdrianLarson Yes, I believe it was fixed in Summer '16 - [View Visualforce Controller Exceptions in Debug Logs](https://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_debugging_logging_vf_exceptions.htm?edition=&impact=)

Comment: @DanielBallinger Thanks for the update. I'm glad we got it fixed. That was a small, but obnoxious problem.